# DateTime::parse_from_str() and assume UTC TZ possible?

Tags: rust

I am attempting to parse the result of a request to `time.nist.gov` and `parse_from_str` is saying there is not enough information to create a DateTime because i'm trying to assume UTC timezone.

Is there a way to `force parse_from_str()` to assume a TimeZone and give me a valid date?

Here is the output from NIST

```
60384 24-03-15 18:21:24 50 0 0 809.2 UTC(NIST) *
```

Here is my code:

```
async fn get_time_from_nist() -> Option<DateTime<FixedOffset>> {
    if let Ok(output) = Command::new("nc").arg("-w 1").arg("time.nist.gov").arg("13").output().await {
        if let Ok(str_out) = String::from_utf8(output.stdout) {
            let str_sub = &str_out[7..25];
            if let Ok(date) = DateTime::parse_from_str(str_sub, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") {
                return Some(date)
            }
        }
    } 
    None
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string doesn't have time zone information, you use [`NaiveDateTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.NaiveDateTime.html).

```rust
if let Ok(date) = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(str_sub, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") {
    return Some(date.and_utc().into());
}
```

`into` is converting `DateTime<Utc>` into `DateTime<FixedOffset>`.

You can also make your code more readable by using `?`.

```rust
async fn get_time_from_nist2() -> Option<DateTime<FixedOffset>> {
    let output = Command::new("nc")
        .arg("-w 1")
        .arg("time.nist.gov")
        .arg("13")
        .output()
        .await
        .ok()?;

    let str_out = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).ok()?;

    let str_sub = &str_out[7..25];
    let date = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(str_sub, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").ok()?;

    Some(date.and_utc().into());
}
```